# How to change the window color to red in assembly?

Tags: winapi, assembly, x86

In TASM for Win32, I have this code:

```
mov     [wc.clsHbrBackground], COLOR_WINDOW + 1
```

I need to change the color of the window to red.  How can I do that?

Comment: There isn't enough information provided to answer this.

Comment: You have to create a brush using `CreateSolidBrush`. Then you use the value returned by `CreateSolidBrush` instead of `COLOR_WINDOW+1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how it works.

```
push    COLOR_RED  ; COLOR_RED dword 255
call    CreateSolidBrush
mov     dword ptr [wc.clsHbrBackground], eax
```